# ie8 split function issue in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to split the string with `'</span>'`. I used the following code

```
var select_value = td_value.split('</span>');
```

It works in fine in FF, chrome. But IE not support this. So i tried the following. But it is not working.

```
var select_value = td_value.split(/</span.*?>/gi);
```

What is  the issue with this? please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to escape the slash:

```
var select_value = td_value.split(/<\/span.*?>/gi);
```